# Alphabetic Substitution, Barcan, and Strict Implication

Tags: logic, modal-logic, symbolic-logic

**Context**: I'm stuck on Axiom 8 from the introduction to Barcan 1946, "A Functional Calculus of First Order Based on Strict Implication." My instinct is that I'm missing a basic, perhaps obvious concept--I don't think that the problem is specific to this axiom or article.

---

**Problem:** Axiom 8 states that

"(α)A ⥽ B, where α and β are individual variables, no free occurrence of α in A is in a wf part of A of the form (β)Γ, and B results from the substitution of β for all free occurrences of α in A." (page 2)

Notes:

- "wf" means "well-formed"
- Barcan uses "(x)" in place of "∀x"

My issue: Suppose A = "γ(α) & γ(β)". I've double checked that this formula is indeed a wff according to Barcan's definition. In this case, how can it *ever* be true that (α)A?

First of all, α must be bound, since Barcan defines 
"(x)G" as "~(∃x)~G" and stipulates that an individual variable x is bound iff it appears in something like "(∃x)F".

Moreover, β must be free, since it is not bound by the existential quantifier. If β is free, then it seems like (α)A has to be neither true nor false, because we don't know what β is.

If we look at C = "γ(α)", then sure, (α)C could be the case. But once we add the γ(β), to get A, I'm struggling to see how (α)A could have a truth value.

If (α)A doesn't have a truth value, how can Axiom 8 be true?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: Some philosophers make themselves look important by being intentionally inscrutable. Sometimes, if a person makes their ideas as easy to understand as possible, it becomes apparent that their ideas are not actually very good. I've read entire books that were that way, cover-to-cover. Sophisticated language is a way of sweeping bad thinking under the rug. Anyone who writes `(α)A`, instead of `∀ α ∈ A` is likely the kind of person who intentionally makes their notation difficult to read so that you can't tell that their arguments are invalid.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon (α)A notation is from Russell's *Principia*, and was most common at the time of Barcan's writing. Gödel and Quine used it too, ∀α ∈ A or ∀αA(α) only spread later. Not conforming to what we are used to today is not always a sign of bad intentions, and [Barcan's ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_Barcan_Marcus) are generally praised as seminal in quantified modal logic and other areas.

Comment: The truth value of "open formulas", i.e. formulas with free occurrences of variables is defined formally in each textbook: there are different approaches available: "equate" them with their universal closure or use variable assignment function (i.e. define a reference for free vars according to a specified "context").

Comment: There is nothing strange here... it is usual first-order logic syntax. Consider a simple example regarding natural numbers : **∀x (x >= 0)**; the subst of y in place of x will produce: **(y >=0)** that is obviously true for every assignment of value to y. The restriction is due in order to avoid errors. Consider now **∀x ∃y (x < y)**; the same subst will produce the wrong **∃y (y < y)**.